# How to resolve AKS Nginx ingress image vulnerability

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

Azure defender is showing vulnerabilities in the Nginx ingress image

[image]

ingress images are in ACR.
I did update the helm repo but it's still showing same issue

I am happy to provide more information if needed

Answer (score 1):

As a first step I would try this:

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/04/28/ingress-nginx-1-2-0/#skip-the-talk-what-do-i-need-to-use-this-new-approach

Second, you can read this to figure out what is the best solution for you.
https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K01051452

You can also take a look here for security issues:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/8372